# IE Blocking same domain iframe communication. (document.domain is set on all iframes)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, same-origin-policy

I have a site that uses an iframe to display a bid request form.  The bid request form instructs the parent window to resize it when needed.  It does this by using a proxy iframe with the same domain as the domain of the top page.

So, (Top Page) Domain A -> (Bid Request Form) Domain B -> (Proxy iframe) Domain A

For some reason this works fine on some sites where the bid request is installed, but not on others...

Here is a working site:  http://5starwindowcare.com/contact/get-a-bid/

And one where it doesn't:  http://windowcleaningservice.net/rfq.php

The iframe should resize a little on load.  Just load IE Internet Tools, start debugging, and leave break on error and you should see the error.

Thanks!

(Am I allowed to give money to the best answer?)  If not, you will have my eternal gratitude.

Joey

Comment: Get some points, and you can put points as bounties on questions.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in chrome too. Pressing Control shift J shows the same error.
looking into the parent of the frame it says:

http://quote.responsibid.com/embed/form/id/1790921346 for the source

the url is different. but may go to the same host. For browsers the domains are different.

Comment: The middle frame is quote.responsibid, but the top domain, and the proxy frame have the same domain.